# How to get the value of select box in jquery and alert that value?

Tags: php, jquery

I have written a jquery code but it is not working for getting the selected option value of a select box. it is alerting the message box not the value which is picked from the select box.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12 padd">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Skill level</label>
    <select name="visa_status" id="visa_status" class="dropselectsec1">
        <option value="bfdgdfgdf">bfdgdfgdf</option>
        <option value="fdfdggf">fdfdggf</option>
        <option value="dfdf">dfdf</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

This is the select box.

jquery code :

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input").change(function(){
            var startDate = $("#start-date").val();
            var endDate = $("#end-date").val();
            $(".rentdate").html("Rental Date<span> From:"+startDate+" To:"+endDate);
        });

        $("select").change(function(){
            var selectedCountry = $(".dropselectsec1 option:selected").val();
            alert(selectedCountry);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `$("select").change(function(){alert($(this).val());});`

Comment: what is not working? -https://jsfiddle.net/y28gt9rn/

Comment: your code works ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(this)` instead.

```
$("select").change(function(){
    var selectedCountry = $(this).val();
    alert(selectedCountry);
});
```

`$(this)` points to the element on which you're binding the event handler. In your case it's selection box.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('select').change(function(){
  var selectedCountry = $(this).val();
  console.log(selectedCountry);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group col-md-12 padd">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Skill level</label>
  <select name="visa_status" id="visa_status" class="dropselectsec1">
    <option value="bfdgdfgdf">bfdgdfgdf</option>
    <option value="fdfdggf">fdfdggf</option>
    <option value="dfdf">dfdf</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following jquery code. ".val()" function will useful to get value of selected dropdown.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#visa_status").change(function(){
        var selectedCountry = $(this).val();
        alert(selectedCountry);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use this

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12 padd">
                                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Skill level</label>
                                    <select name="visa_status" id="visa_status" class="dropselectsec1">

                                                    <option value="bfdgdfgdf">bfdgdfgdf</option>
                                                    <option value="fdfdggf">fdfdggf</option>
                                                    <option value="dfdf">dfdf</option>
                                                </select>
                                </div>

                                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#visa_status").change(function(){
    var selectedCountry = $(".dropselectsec1 option:selected").val();
    alert(selectedCountry);
});


</script>
```